# "Run north of" meaning in the context

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-meaning

> The 30-year fixed rate mortgage has run north of 6% all year.

I saw the sentence from [here](https://edition.cnn.com/2023/05/03/success/mortgages-what-rising-interest-rates-mean-for-home-loans-tenth-hike/index.html). In my opinion, the word 'north' is a slang usage as defined in [the free dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/north):

> **Slang**, Into a better condition, as of increased value: *an investment that went steadily north until the market crash*.

But I'm not 100% sure about it. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: This metaphoric use of "north of..." isn't about *better condition* - it's just ***higher*** (North is always at the ***top*** of the map).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In that context, "north of" means "above" or "higher than".

You won't necessarily find it in dictionaries because it plays on the universal understanding that north is up, so if something is "north of 6%", it must be higher than 6%.

Comment: I see. And do we really use the word 'south' for the opposite concept, e.g. *run south of 6%*?

Comment: Yes, we can use "south" to mean "less than" or "under". It's less common, and almost always has a negative feeling about it, so while we might talk about voter turnout rates going south of X% (a bad thing), we'd never talk about suicide rates "going south of " X% (a good thing).

Comment: I'm not sure south is *always* used in a negative sense.  Pretty sure I've heard it used recently to describe the unemployment rates dipping below some value.  It is *usually* negative, but I think there are exceptions.

Comment: The figurative meaning is found in the OED: " Higher; esp. in north of (a figure, cost, etc.): higher than, in excess of".

Comment: @DarrelHoffman if you google the phrase "unemployment south of" (with the quotes) there's a mix of the literal meaning - "unemployment south of the border" and the like - and the figurative, for example in a Barron's article from 1998 which (https://www.barrons.com/articles/SB941850332801632107) which refers to "U.S. growth north of 3% and unemployment south of 5%."

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - I think saying it's "usually negative" is only true insofar as "down" in general is usually negative. I don't think there's anything else in that.

Comment: @gotube, I fundamentally disagree, I've referred to places as having "rents south of £X" plenty.

Comment: I don't think e.g. "south of 6%^ means bad, but this is complicated a little because there is the related phrase "it went south from there" which is unequivocally a bad thing

Comment: "North of" just means "higher than".  This can be a bad thing if the statistic that it's referring to is a bad thing: crime, unemployment, inflation, high school dropout rate, etc.